# Esperar 1 minuto até que um valor seja alterado no banco de dados

Tags: php

Ainda não desenvolvi o script devido à seguinte dúvida. Quero que o PHP aguarde um determinado tempo até que o valor do banco de dados seja alterado, senão ele redireciona para a página principal.

**Por exemplo:**

1. Vou inserir um dado em MySQL com a minha `pagina.php`.
2. Outra pessoa irá alterar este dado, de outro dispositivo.
3. A `pagina.php` irá aguardar até um minuto, e se isso não ocorrer, irá enviar para `index.php`.

Comment: Olá, Augusto! Seja bem  vindo ao SOPT! É sempre bom postar o código que você já tem (mesmo que seja apenas uma ideia) para que possamos entender o contexto e realmente a sua necessidade... De qualquer forma, dê uma olhada sobre o [sleep](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sleep.php), talvez te ajude

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou ver como fica implementado.

Comment: O ruim do sleep é que ele deveria executar o código pelo menos de um contador e postar o número em segundo, e ele só da a função echo no final da contagem.